# Grab staff's manager email and send as "assigned to" using ms flow?

Tags: sharepoint-online, approval, microsoft-flow

I'm having difficulty on SharePoint list with ms workflow.

I've created **New Request** sp list and **Requested Order** sp list, then **Employee** sp list.

So, Employee List has Manager Column which includes name, email addresses and also Staff Column which includes names, email addresses. Each list item has staffs info in one column and their manager's name & email address in another column within the same Item.

I'm using ms flow approval where "Assigned to" - I need to have business logic that "Assigned to" should go to respective email of the manager.

for example: as shown in the screenshot.
[image: List columns]

Business logic should be like **If logged in user is staff then should pick his manager and send an email for approval**

thanks
Fera

Comment: Hey Fera, can you please elaborate more. In which list you are adding MS Flow, and what are the business steps involved.

Comment: Hi ThinkB4Code, thanks for your reply! My flow is getting input from ms form web.So  Create Item by using Get Items from Employee SP List -> New Request SP List, once New Request is created then Start and Wait for an Approval (Assigned To - email address) and then once manager approves, approved item will created on Requested Order SP List.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, following are three list you are working with.

1. **Employee List**: Keep a track of Unit Manager and Employees within it.
2. **New Request List**: All the new request are logged in here by end users.
3. **Requested Orders**: Once the Unit Manger Approve a request, automatically a order must be created here.

Base on above problem, I am using an assumptions here that in Employee list contains the `Unit Manager` column is single-select People only and not enforcing unique values and `Staff Member` is multi-select People only column. Also, I am using a lookup column in `New Request` from `Employee` list to get the manager. If this not the case, in MS Flow, where I am using `SharePoint Get Item` you can modify it make a `REST API Call to SP` to get the right manager. Remaining logic remains same in MS Flow.

For reference use the URL to see how to [create approval workflow in MS Flow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/flow/modern-approvals).

**Overall MS Flow:**

[image]

**Step 1:**
I added the MS Flow to `New Request` list. The flow will trigger as a new item is created in this list. The `Employee` list and `Request` list schema is following, while the order list in my case contains only Title column.

[image]

[image]

**Step 2:** Here I am using the trick to get the Manager Email ID using lookup column. In case you are not using lookup, either use `SharePoint Get Item` action or [`Send HTTP Request to SharePoint`](https://blogs.msmvps.com/windsor/2018/06/15/calling-the-sharepoint-rest-api-in-a-microsoft-flow/). The flow configuration is following:

[image]

**Step 3:** Once we have the Manager Email ID, we need to use `Start an Approval` MS Flow action. Except the `Assign To` all other values are filled using `New Request` List.

[image]

**Step 4:** Now add parallel branches based on `approval` condition we can make the decision. If the Approval is 'Yes' we have a set of logic to `create a new item in Order list` and send `confirmation` mail, otherwise send the mail to initiator saying `request rejected` and adding `Unit Manager comments`.

[image]

This completes our approval flow. On Approve we are adding a new item to `Order` list, if rejected we are just notifying the user. Also to note, this will trigger only when a new item is created. If user modifies the request nothing will happen. They need to submit a new request. We can modify the logic by triggering flow on `when item modified`.